# How to denote the fifth derivative in Newton’s notation?

Tags: math-mode, accents

I am trying to set five dots on the top of a letter in order to denote the fifth derivative in Newton’s notation. If I do 
one dot  `\dot{X}`,
two dots `\ddot{X}`,
three dots `\dddot{X}`,
four dots `\dddot{X}`
it's fine. But when you are going to five dots this command is not working. like:
five dots `\dddddot{X}`.

Do you have any idea how to set five dots?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but is it advisable to use Newton’s notation for such high-order derivatives? Having to count the number of dots is imho the red line; your readers might find d^5/dt^5 clearer.

Comment: @Zozor: Yes, that is true indeed. But the point is that my 5th order diff equation is really big(You may look at the equation 8 of this paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physleta.2018.03.011). Now,  when you are explaining or solving certain things using this equation it's become really huge especially in two-column LaTeX format. Then it's easy to use dots instead of proper notation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that each macro has to be defined, and there is only up to `\ddddot`.

So I made two macros: `\dddddot`, and `\multidots`. For both of them I copied the definition of `\ddddot` and added dots.

`\dddddot` will put five dots on top of its argument. `\multidots{n}{arg}` will put `n` dots on top of `arg`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\long\def\dddddot#1{%
  {\mathop {#1}\limits ^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@ {\kern -\tw@ \ex@ \hbox {\normalfont .....}\vss }}}%
}
\long\def\multidots#1#2{%
  \count@=0
  {{\mathop {#2}\limits ^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@ {\kern -\tw@ \ex@ \hbox {\normalfont %
  \loop%
  \ifnum#1>\count@%
  .%
  \advance\count@ by1%
  \repeat%
  }\vss }}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\dot{X}$ two dots $\ddot{X}$ three dots $\dddot{X}$ four dots $\ddddot{X}$ five dots $\dddddot{X}$

$\multidots{1}{X}$ two dots $\multidots{2}{X}$ three dots $\multidots{3}{X}$ four dots $\multidots{4}{X}$ five dots $\multidots{5}{X}$ lots of dots $\multidots{15}{X}$
\end{document}
```

---

We can add an `\hbox to 0pt` to hide the width of the dots and make the spacing right on the sides of the `X`. Although the dots will go over the rest of the text... It's a matter of choice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\long\def\dddddot#1{%
  {\mathop {#1}\limits ^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@ {\kern -\tw@ \ex@ \hbox {\normalfont .....}\vss }}}%
}
\long\def\multidots#1#2{%
  \count@=0
  {{\mathop {#2}\limits ^{\hbox to 0pt{\vbox to-1.4\ex@ {\kern -\tw@ \ex@ \hbox {\normalfont %
  \loop%
  \ifnum#1>\count@%
  .%
  \advance\count@ by1%
  \repeat%
  }\vss }}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\dot{X}$ two dots $\ddot{X}$ three dots $\dddot{X}$ four dots $\ddddot{X}$ five dots $\dddddot{X}$

$\multidots{1}{X}$ two dots $\multidots{2}{X}$ three dots $\multidots{3}{X}$ four dots $\multidots{4}{X}$ five dots $\multidots{5}{X}$ lots of dots $\multidots{15}{X}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Phelype : Perhaps it is better to call `\newcount` outside the macro. Theoretically one could run out of count registers. Or even better, use `\numexpr` whose value is assigned to an ordinary token list variable (via `\edef`).

Comment: @AlexG Indeed, thanks for pointing that out :) I used a temporary count register `\count@`.

Answer (score 4):

Though @Phelype Oleinik said it more precisely and appropriate way. Here I find a shortcut and easiest way to set five dots to describe 5th derivative on top. Where you don't have to specify anything.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
   \overset{.....}{X}
  %\overset{<how many dots you want - put that many [dot]s here>}{X}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a very neat solution too :) Just one thing: notice the difference between `\overset{.....}{X}` and `\overset{\hbox{.....}}{X}`. I prefer the latter. Also, if you liked the second version of my answer, you can use `\overset{\hbox to 0pt{.....}}{X}` to hide the width of the dots.